# Spring Two factor authentication where to save credentials

Tags: spring, authentication, two-factor-authentication

I'm trying to implement two factor authentication in my Spring application.

**Desired situation**

I want the user to first log in with his username and password, if those are correct I want the system to generate a random key and email that to the user. After that the system has to redirect the user to a page where he only has to enter the token and login to the system.

**What I got so far (in pseudo code)**

User enters the login.jsp page. Upon logging in with username/password the system sends out a CustomMade AuthenticationException. In the AuthenticationFailureHandler I do a getAuthentication on the exception (I'm aware of deprecacy) But I use the username to send the user his token. After that I put the exception in the session (using request.getSession().setAttribute ) and finally the system reloads the login.jsp.

Login.jsp sees the exception in the session and shows the token input field. User fills the token input field and logs in. System authenticates the user with the credentials in the session and the given token.

**Question**

I think it's bad practice to save the username/password in session. Two possible solutions I thought of:

1. After checking Username/Password. Save the username in a static variable or in DB. When user is entering the token check whether username is in the variable/db and check the token. If the token is correct do a login with the user.
2. After checking username / password log the user in with a low role. With the low role the user can only go to the token page, after entering a valid token the system gives the user new authorities.

What would be the best solution to implement?

Comment: email is not a good second factor, why not SMS or TOTP?

Comment: Please enlighten me why sending the token via email wouldn't be a good idea. I'm using TOTP already to create the token. The secret is generated randomly and saved in the database.

Comment: If a hacker steals my laptop and tries to login to your site, he could have access to my email too! If you use a phone as a second factor, then he would need to steal both my laptop and phone.

Comment: either way, what you want to do is let the user login as normal, strip their Authorities, give them NEEDS_2FA authority and redirect to 2FA screen. If they pass 2FA, restore their authorities. see http://www.gobloomhealth.com/multi-factor-authentication-part-1/